# How to change method of Google 2-factor authentication?

Tags: gmail, google-account, security, multi-factor-auth

I used to have a reasonable system:

1. log into Google web account
2. get a push sent to my Google app (iOS) that required me to hit "Yes this is me"

I had the Google authenticator app installed on my phone, but it didn't serve a purpose anymore.

After a recent app update (which I rarely do), Google now requires me to use the authenticator app code instead of getting a push to my Google app. I am still logged in on all apps.

I have to log in on new computers constantly, so this is a huge nuisance. Is there a way I can switch back to the "Push" method of 2-factor authentication?

Google's guides make it sound like there should be an option under account security, but I don't see it there. I think I've gone through every menu option on my Google account.

Comment: Interesting; I have the opposite problem - Google keeps insisting that I use the non-working push notification, when every time I change it to use TOTP (what they dishonestly call "Google Authenticator" even though it is nothing Google-specific).

Comment: FYI, the relevant setting is [here](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification), but there's no option to change the default without logging *out* of Google on my phone >:(